# Tailwind style esp. translate-x sometimes working and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Here is where I am using tailwind classes.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import LeftNavMenuItem from './LeftNavMenuItem'
import { categories } from "../utils/constants"
import { Context } from "../context/contextApi"

const LeftNav = () => {
    const { selectCategory, setSelectCategory, mobileMenu } = useContext(Context)

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const clickHandler = (name, type) => {
        switch (type) {
            case "category":
                return setSelectCategory(name)
            case "home":
                return setSelectCategory(name)
            case "menu":
                return false
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={`md:block w-[240px] overflow-y-auto h-full py-4 bg-black absolute md:relative z-10 translate-x-[-240px] md:translate-x-0 transform transition-all ${mobileMenu ? "translate-x-0" : ""}`}>
            <div className="flex px-5 flex-col">
                {categories.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment key={item.name}>
                            <LeftNavMenuItem
                                text={item?.type === 'home' ? "Home" : item?.name}
                                icon={item?.icon}
                                action={() => {
                                    clickHandler(item?.name, item?.type)
                                    navigate('/')
                                }}
                                className={`${selectCategory === item?.name ? "bg-white/[0.15]" : ""}`}
                                mobileMenu={mobileMenu}
                            />
                            {item?.divider && (
                                <hr className='my-5 border-white/[0.2]' />
                            )}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })}
                <hr className='my-5 border-white/[0.2]' />
                <div className="text-white/[0.5] text-[12px]">
                    Clone by: Manash
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LeftNav
```

Here is the tailwind.config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  mode: 'jit',
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am expecting when this below button is clicked it should show the menu like below

[image: Button to be clicked]

[image: expectation]

But sometimes its working fine and sometimes not. I am not able to figure out what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have only one class per property for the same property applied to the same element at any one time. You have conflicting `translate-x-[-240px]` and `translate-x-0` classes at the same time on the element when `mobileMenu` is truthy. Consider only having one of these classes active on the element, like:

```
<div className={`md:block w-[240px] overflow-y-auto h-full py-4 bg-black absolute md:relative z-10 md:translate-x-0 transform transition-all ${mobileMenu ? "translate-x-0" : "translate-x-[-240px]"}`>
```